# How to extract first floating numbers appearing after a word?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to build an application for text extraction use case but I was not able to extract exact price from it.

I have a text like this,

```
string1 = 'Friscos #8603\n8100 E. Orchard Road\nGreenwood Village, Colorado 80111\n2013-11-02\nTable 00\nGuest\n1 Oysters 1/2 Shell #1\n1 Crab Cake\n1 Filet 1602 Bone In\n1 Ribeye 22oz Bone In\n1 Asparagus\n1 Potato Au Gratin\n$17.00\n$19.00\n$66.00\n$53.00\n$12.00\n$11.50\nSub Total\nTax\n$178.50\n$12.94\nTotal\n$191.44\n'
string2 = 'Berghotel\nGrosse Scheidegg\n3818 Grindelwald\nFamilie R. Müller\nRech. Nr. 4572\nBar\n30.07.2007/13:29:17\nTisch 7/01\nNM\n#ರ\n2xLatte Macchiato à 4.50 CHF\n1xGloki\nà 5.00 CHF\n1xSchweinschnitzel à 22.00 CHF\n1xChässpätzli à 18.50 CHF\n#ರ #ರ #1ರ\n5.00\n22.00\n18.50\nTotal:\nCHF\n54.50\nIncl. 7.6% MwSt\n54.50 CHF:\n3.85\nEntspricht in Euro 36.33 EUR\nEs bediente Sie: Ursula\nMwSt Nr. : 430 234\nTel.: 033 853 67 16\nFax.: 033 853 67 19\nE-mail: grossescheidegg@bluewin.ch\n'
```

I want to extract the **price** that appearing after the word **total** using regex but I was only able to extract all floating numbers. Also do note some-times you may also see words such as `sub total` but I only need price that appears after the word `total`. Also sometimes after total there may occur other words as well. So Regex should match word total and extract the floating numbers that appears next to it.

Any help is appreciated.

This is what I've tried,

```
re.findall("\d+\.\d+", string1) # this returns all floating numbers.
```

Comment: both `Total\nTax\n$178.50\n$12.94\nTotal\n$191.44\n` of `string1`?

Comment: If you see the string1 for the first total it's not just total it's "sub total"? I only need to extract floating numbers after the word total just total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
(?<=\\nTotal)\:?\D+([\d\.]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KeNg0h/1)

Comment: This is good, but I think OP soon realizes he also needs '$' or 'CHF'.... 

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, should work for the example and the other restrictions you mentioned

```
import re
result = re.search('Total\n\$(\d+.\d+)', string1)
result.group(1) # 191.44
result = re.search('Total\:\n.+\n(\d+.\d+)', string2)
result.group(1) # 54.50
```

EDIT: If you want only one expression for both, you could try

```
result = re.search('\nTotal\:?(\n\D+)*\n\$?(\d+.\d+)', string)
re.group(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookbehind to prevent `sub` being before `total`, word boundaries to prevent the words being part of a larger word and a capturing group to capture the price.

```
(?<!\bsub )\btotal\b\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

In parts:

- `(?<!\bsub )` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not the word sub and a space
- `\btotal\b` Match total between word boundaries to prevent it being part of a larger word
- `\D*` Match 0+ times any char that is not a digit
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1LAyf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KIkl8W)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\bsub )\btotal\b\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+))"
string1 = 'Friscos #8603\n8100 E. Orchard Road\nGreenwood Village, Colorado 80111\n2013-11-02\nTable 00\nGuest\n1 Oysters 1/2 Shell #1\n1 Crab Cake\n1 Filet 1602 Bone In\n1 Ribeye 22oz Bone In\n1 Asparagus\n1 Potato Au Gratin\n$17.00\n$19.00\n$66.00\n$53.00\n$12.00\n$11.50\nSub Total\nTax\n$178.50\n$12.94\nTotal\n$191.44\n'
string2 = 'Berghotel\nGrosse Scheidegg\n3818 Grindelwald\nFamilie R. Müller\nRech. Nr. 4572\nBar\n30.07.2007/13:29:17\nTisch 7/01\nNM\n#ರ\n2xLatte Macchiato à 4.50 CHF\n1xGloki\nà 5.00 CHF\n1xSchweinschnitzel à 22.00 CHF\n1xChässpätzli à 18.50 CHF\n#ರ #ರ #1ರ\n5.00\n22.00\n18.50\nTotal:\nCHF\n54.50\nIncl. 7.6% MwSt\n54.50 CHF:\n3.85\nEntspricht in Euro 36.33 EUR\nEs bediente Sie: Ursula\nMwSt Nr. : 430 234\nTel.: 033 853 67 16\nFax.: 033 853 67 19\nE-mail: grossescheidegg@bluewin.ch\n'

print(re.findall(regex, string1, re.IGNORECASE))
print(re.findall(regex, string2, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output

```
['191.44']
['54.50']
```

---

If what precedes the price should be a dollar sign of the text CHF, you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(?:\$|CHF)\s*` matching of the values followed by matching 0+ whitespace chars:

```
(?<!\bsub )\btotal\b\D*(?:\$|CHF)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYiGVv/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
(?<!sub )total.*?(\d+.\d+)
```

Make sure to ignore the case.